# python boundary regex and \+ symbol

Tags: python, regex

I don't know why regex not working.

This works:

```
import re

text = 'this phone is +44 64646464 , call me'

chunk_text = "phone is"
regex_pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(chunk_text)}\b"

assert re.search(regex_pattern, text)
```

this doesn't work:

```
import re

text = 'this phone is +44 64646464 , call me'


chunk_text = "+44"
regex_pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(chunk_text)}\b"

assert re.search(regex_pattern, text) # this don't pass
```

don't read this is only random words because some intelligent developer from stack overflow consider that my post is mostly code.

Comment: If you do not want to guess when to use `\b` and when not to use `\b`, just use `regex_pattern = rf"(?!\B\w){re.escape(chunk_text)}(?!\B\w)"`